# Calculating an angle from an intersecting rectangle and circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I've been trying to do some trigonometry to find an equation for a bevel angle for a tool (the rectangle in the diagram below) ground on a rest using a circular grinding stone (the large arc in the diagram below).  I think I've formulated the problem with all the variables I know and I think there's enough there to fully define the angle, but I'm really struggling to figure out to link the tool thickness (t) into the equations.

This is how I've formulated the problem:

[image: Problem Definition]

All of the blue dimensions are defined and known.  All of the red lines indicate some of the angles and lengths that I've got equations for already.  There are a few more that are quite straightforward from those angles (e.g. just 180°-something) but I was trying not to make the diagram too cluttered.

I'm trying to derive $\theta$ in terms of the $r$, $l$, $t$, $s$ and $g$.  None of the equations I've written (and deemed useful) have included $t$ so far, which is obviously a problem!

Close-up of the angle I'm interested in, in case it isn't clear (with the red lines removed for clarity):

[image: Angle of interest]

Can anyone help me relate the triangles to the chords?

I can draw it in CAD and get the angle out very easily, but that feels to me like it's cheating and I'd like to understand the trigonometry involved!

Edit: this is the same thing redrawn with g doubled to show the differences in alphas:

[image: Doubled g]

Edit 2: Long-winded solution based on the first set of help that John Alexiou has given (but note that the solution offered by John in his edited answer is much more elegant).

[image: Solution]

Comment: Without loss of generality, you can rotate the tool to be horizontal which would make the construction easier to understand and describe.

Comment: You should probably add the solution as a new answer and not as part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality of the problem, we rotate it such that the tool is horizontal.

An example of this construction is shown below, verifying in CAD that the position is defined from the dimensions $r$, $\ell$, $s$ and $g$ only. The dimension $t$ is used later to define where the bottom of the tool intersects the circle.

[image: fig1]

And now for the characterization of this problem:

- **Step 1**, Given dimensions $r$, $\ell$, $s$ and $g$ below, find the polar angles $\varphi$ and $\psi$. The polar angle $\varphi$ is the most important here, as it can be used to define the coordinates $(x,y)$ of the top left corner of the tool.

  [image: fig2]

  From the sketch above you have the following two equations tracing a point from the circle center to the top left corner of the tool, then across $\ell$ and down $s$ and around to the center again.

  $$ \begin{aligned}
   (r+g) \cos \psi = r \cos \varphi + \ell \\
   (r+g) \sin \psi = r \sin \varphi -s \\
   \end{aligned} $$

  Take both equations, square them and add them up to get to

  $$\left. (g+r)^2 = 2 \ell r \cos \varphi - 2 s r \sin \varphi + \ell^2 + s^2 + r^2 \right\} \\ \ell \cos \varphi - s \sin \varphi = \frac{g^2+2 g r-\ell^2-s^2}{2 r} $$

  The last equation can be written as $\ell \cos \varphi - s \sin \varphi = \kappa$ with the definition of the variable $\kappa = \frac{g^2+2 g r-\ell^2-s^2}{2 r}$

  The solution of the above is

  $$\varphi = \frac{\pi}{2} - \sin^{-1}\left( \frac{\kappa}{\sqrt{\ell^2+s^2}}\right) - \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{s}{\ell} \right) \tag{1}$$

  using the example values from the first figure, this results in $\varphi = 59.84°$.

  Finding the angle $\psi$ is done by dividing the two equations above to get

  $$ \psi = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{r \sin \varphi - s}{r \cos \varphi + \ell}\right) \tag{2}$$

  Note that the above can be positive or negative, depending on how long $s$ is.
- **Step 2**, Finding the desired angle $\theta$ shown below from the tool thickness $t$

  [image: fig3]

  In a similar fashion, we trace a point from the center of the circle to the top left of the tool, but now we go down by $t$ and across by the unknown $u$ length, and finally back to the center.

  This produces the following two equations

  $$\begin{aligned}
    r \cos\varphi + u = r \cos \gamma \\
    r \sin\varphi - t = r \sin \gamma \\
    \end{aligned}$$

  And again we square them and add them to produce $$ 2 r u \cos \varphi - 2 r t \sin \varphi +t^2 + u^2 = 0$$

  which is directly solved for the triangle length $u$ as

  $$ u = \sqrt{ r^2 \cos^2 \varphi + 2 r t \sin \varphi-t^2} - r \cos \varphi \tag{3}$$

  Using the example values from above, I get $u = 8.40658$ using $t = 8$.

  and the auxiliary angle $$\gamma = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{r \sin \varphi-t}{r \cos\varphi+u} \right) \tag{4} $$

  From the lengths $t$ and $u$, the desired angle $\theta$ is found with

  $$\boxed{ \theta = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{t}{u} \right) } \tag{5}$$

  And finally with the example geometry from above, $\theta = 43.5804°$

  [image: fig5]

  which is the same value I measure in CAD.

In summary, use equations (1),(3) and (5) to get the answer

$$\begin{aligned}
\kappa & = \frac{g^2+2 g r-\ell^2-s^2}{2 r} \\
\varphi & = \frac{\pi}{2} - \sin^{-1}\left( \frac{\kappa}{\sqrt{\ell^2+s^2}}\right) - \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{s}{\ell} \right) \\ u & = \sqrt{ r^2 \cos^2 \varphi + 2 r t \sin \varphi-t^2} - r \cos \varphi \\ \theta & = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{t}{u} \right) \\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I updated the answer. Can you check if it gives the correct result?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I'm still working through it, so I'll confirm whether it matches everything as soon as I can.  One thing that doesn't make sense to me (and doesn't match the CAD drawing I've done) is the two $\alpha$s in the second diagram.  For those two angles to be the same assumes that the red line that joins the two $\alpha$-marked corners together is at right-angles to the radius-line.  I'm not sure why it should be (and in the CAD drawing, it isn't).

If I'm understanding this right, you need that to be true to be able to work out $\alpha$, no?

Comment: Actually, I think I can work out the left $\alpha$ another way (using g, the red angles and the two red lengths). I'll try to work it all through and see if it makes sense.

Comment: The two α angles belong to sides of perpendicular lines. Perpendicular to the radial line is the red line on the top α, and perpendicular to the $s$ is the $\ell$ line. I edited the answer with the calculation for $\alpha$ from the given lengths.

Comment: I've added another version of the diagram to the end of the question.  In this diagram, I doubled the length of $g$ but kept all the other defined lengths ($t$, $l$, $s$, $r$) the same.  The tool (rectangle) is now close to vertical and it's fairly obvious I think that the red line isn't perpendicular to the radial line.  The two angles I've marked $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ look different to me too.

Comment: But isn't the red line tangent to the circle? Maybe I misunderstood the construction.

Comment: The red lines were both just lines I added as I was trying to work my way towards the angle I was interested in.  There's no reason I can see that it should be tangent to the circle.  In case some context would help, this is the sort of thing I'm trying to model: https://blog.axminstertools.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/tormek_se77_01.jpg - the bar (which moves in and out and about which the tool holder pivots) is represented by the point at the outer end of $g$.  $s$ is the distance from the pivot point to the top of the tool.

Comment: Knowing now that I need to work out $\alpha_1$, I think I can solve it (it'll be interesting to see how it simplifies).  I'll work through the maths later and see what it comes up with.

Comment: I've now added a very long-winded solution based on knowing that I needed $\alpha$ and $\beta$ but without the assumption that the red line is tangent to the circle.  I haven't tried to simplify it yet!  It obviously isn't very elegant; I'd welcome a simpler alternative, but for what I need I think this will work.  If you update your answer to remove the assumption that the red line is tangent, then I'll happily mark it as accepted.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I completely re-did my answer, based on my current understanding of the question. Please check again.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response to this: the last couple of days have been very busy.  Anyway, I've now checked this through carefully and I think it's an excellent and elegant solution.  I've checked it against my CAD model and my long-winded version.  I've also used the same method to derive equations going the other way (known $\theta$ and unknown $l$).  That's been really useful, thank you for your help.